# Character are omitting while sending request to server(Spring Boot) from client (NodeJS)

Tags: java, node.js, spring-boot, node-rest-client

I have `Spring Boot` and `NodeJS` application. Where `Spring boot` has set of API which are called from `NodeJS` application.

Because of business requirement, I am encrypting some value on `Spring Boot` application and sending it to `NodeJS` application.

In application flow, I had to send encrypted token from `NodeJS` application to `Spring Boot` application where I will be doing decryption for further processing.

Now, when I send encrypted token to `Spring Boot` application, I see some the character are omitting. For example, `+` is replaced with (new line or empty string) and due to this I am not able to perform decryption.

To be more explicit, `..1nfppOsSaMxTBIPq1x16K9L68Mo+JaaDNrgiNvkdWVOasyRCeh7rsEJEyd/syxiO..` replaced with `..1nfppOsSaMxTBIPq1x16K9L68Mo JaaDNrgiNvkdWVOasyRCeh7rsEJEyd/syxiO..`. I think, its something to do with `encoding` or `escaping` of character.

I tried to set `content-type` in request header but no luck.
Can someone help me, how to fix this issue?

On `NodeJS` side, I am using `node-rest-client` to send `POST` request. `AES` algorithm is used for encryption and decryption.

Comment: Are you using HTTP or another protocol?? if http whats the content-type of request header

Comment: Content-type is "application/json" but the issue was with encoding as mentioned in answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, your token was sent as url param, and the server tries to decode it. 
Just try to encode token on client side using `encodeURIComponent` function.